# Switch case of buttons selection in jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

Does anyone know how to reduce my code below or make it easier ?
The code is intended to choose three buttons of thirty buttons.
So I can see some information by selected three buttons that I am interesting.
Actually the code includes 8 selection buttons so far, but I need to make 30 buttons.

----------------------my code-----------------------------

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button2").click(function(){
    $("#myNav1").fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $(".closebtn").click(function(){
      $("#myNav1").animate({width: '0px'});
    });
  var counter = 0;
  $("button").bind("click",function(){
var btnid = this.id;
if ( counter < 4) {
switch (btnid){ case "btn1": switch (counter){
     case 0 : $("#img1").attr("src","icon/1.jpg");counter ++; break;
     case 1 : $("#img2").attr("src","icon/1.jpg");counter ++; break;
     case 2 : $("#img3").attr("src","icon/1.jpg");counter ++; break;
     case 3 : alert("Please Select result button");counter = 0 ; break;
   } break;
  case "btn2": switch (counter){
    case 0 :  $("#img1").attr("src","icon/2.jpg");counter ++; break;
    case 1 :  $("#img2").attr("src","icon/2.jpg");counter ++; break;
    case 2 :  $("#img3").attr("src","icon/2.jpg");counter ++; break;
    case 3 :  alert("Please Select result button"); counter = 0 ; break;
  }  break;
  case "btn3": switch (counter){
    case 0 :  $("#img1").attr("src","icon/3.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 1 :  $("#img2").attr("src","icon/3.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 2 :  $("#img3").attr("src","icon/3.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 3 :  alert("Please Select result button");counter = 0 ;break;
  } break;
  case "btn4": switch (counter){
    case 0 : $("#img1").attr("src","icon/4.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 1 : $("#img2").attr("src","icon/4.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 2 : $("#img3").attr("src","icon/4.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 3 : alert("Please Select result button");counter = 0 ; break;
  } break;
  case "btn4": switch (counter){
    case 0 : $("#img1").attr("src","icon/4.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 1 : $("#img2").attr("src","icon/4.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 2 : $("#img3").attr("src","icon/4.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 3 : alert("Please Select result button");counter = 0 ; break;
  } break;
  case "btn5": switch (counter){
    case 0 : $("#img1").attr("src","icon/5.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 1 : $("#img2").attr("src","icon/5.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 2 : $("#img3").attr("src","icon/5.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 3 : alert("Please Select result button");counter = 0 ; break;
  } break;
  case "btn6": switch (counter){
    case 0 : $("#img1").attr("src","icon/6.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 1 : $("#img2").attr("src","icon/6.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 2 : $("#img3").attr("src","icon/6.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 3 : alert("Please Select result button");counter = 0 ; break;
  } break;
  case "btn7": switch (counter){
    case 0 : $("#img1").attr("src","icon/7.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 1 : $("#img2").attr("src","icon/7.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 2 : $("#img3").attr("src","icon/7.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 3 : alert("Please Select result button");counter = 0 ; break;
  } break;
  case "btn8": switch (counter){
    case 0 : $("#img1").attr("src","icon/8.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 1 : $("#img2").attr("src","icon/8.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 2 : $("#img3").attr("src","icon/8.jpg");counter ++;break;
    case 3 : alert("Please Select result button");counter = 0 ; break;
  } break;
  case "btn9": switch (counter) {
    case 0:  break;
    case 1:  $("#img1").attr("src","");counter --; break;
    case 2:  $("#img2").attr("src","");counter --; break;
    case 3:  $("#img3").attr("src","");counter --; break;
  } break;
      }
  }
else{
alert("Please Select result button");
counter = 0 ;
  }
  });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button2">HTML Start Button</button>
<button id="button3">HTML Reset Button</button>
<div class="btnCl">
<button id="btn1">11</button>
<button id="btn2">22</button>
<button id="btn3">33</button>
<button id="btn4">44</button>
<button id="btn5">55</button>
<button id="btn6">66</button>
<button id="btn7">77</button>
<button id="btn8">88</button>
<button id="btn9">return</button>
</div>

<div  id="myNav1" class="overlay">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" >&times;</a>
<div class="overlay-content">
<h1>Selected Contents</h1>
          <div class="imgCl">
    <img id="img1" src="" alt=""></img>
      <img id="img2" src="" alt=""></img>
        <img id="img3" src="" alt=""></img>
        </div>
      </br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to have something generic like this. Create variables for the limits. eg `buttonEnd = 9;`. Then use them inside the code. You can change that based on the number of buttons.

```js
var counter = 0;
var buttonEnd = 9;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#myNav1").fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $(".closebtn").click(function() {
    $("#myNav1").animate({
      width: '0px'
    });
  });
  $("button").bind("click", function() {
    var btnid = Number(this.id.replace('btn', ''));
    if (counter < 4) {
      if (btnid < buttonEnd) {
        if (counter == 3) {
          alert("Please Select result button");
          counter = 0;
        } else {
          $("#img" + (counter + 1)).attr("src", "icon/" + btnid + ".jpg");
          counter++;
        }

      } else {
        $("#img" + (counter)).attr("src", "");
        counter--;
      }
    } else {
      alert("Please Select result button");
      counter = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button2">HTML Start Button</button>
<button id="button3">HTML Reset Button</button>
<div class="btnCl">
  <button id="btn1">11</button>
  <button id="btn2">22</button>
  <button id="btn3">33</button>
  <button id="btn4">44</button>
  <button id="btn5">55</button>
  <button id="btn6">66</button>
  <button id="btn7">77</button>
  <button id="btn8">88</button>
  <button id="btn9">return</button>
</div>

<div id="myNav1" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <h1>Selected Contents</h1>
    <div class="imgCl">
      <img id="img1" src="" alt=""></img>
      <img id="img2" src="" alt=""></img>
      <img id="img3" src="" alt=""></img>
    </div>
    </br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 0;
$("button").bind("click",function() {
    var btnid = $(this).id;
    var img;
    if (counter++ < 3) {    
        var img = "icon/" + btnid + ".jpg";
        $("#img" + counter).attr("src",img);
    }
    else alert("Please Select result button");
}
```

You just have to change the btn-ids to plain numbers (without the "btn") and can then use it as variables für the image name. (Or change the image names to "btn1.jpg, ...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to reduce the part of "case "btn1": switch (counter)" ~ "case "btn8": switch (counter)" though? Actually what I intended is to select three buttons of thirty buttons then put new image by the selected button to the three place holders mentioned #img1, #img2, #img3 in my code.

Comment: So to get you right: The images should show up when all three buttons has been clicked? or one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all the switch like that :

```
if(counter < 3) {
   $("#img" + (counter + 1)).attr("src","icon/" + btnid + ".jpg");
   counter ++;
}
else {
  alert("Please Select result button");
  counter = 0;
}
```